# DISTINCT results from db using sql query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I am working in Zend Framework 2.
How do I get only unique values for **jobtitle** from this query??

```
$jobselect = $jobstable->select()
                        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                        ->from($jobsname, array("$jobsname.title as jobtitle", "$jobsname.company as company", "$storagename.storage_path as companylogo", "$jobsname.location as location"))
                        ->join($storagename, "$storagename.parent_id = $jobsname.job_id")    
                        ->where("$storagename.parent_type = ?", "job")
                        ->where("$storagename.type = ?", "thumb.icon")
                        ->where("$jobsname.user_id = ?", 244);
```

Comment: This is not related to ZF2. It is an SQL Q. Rewrite the Q with clean SQL and declare what you wish to be unique

Comment: In addition of @michaelbn use GROUP BY for your sql.

Answer (score 0):

```
->where("$jobsname.user_id = ?", 244)
-group("jobtitle");
```